# Using a NSFetchedResultController, the delete button does nothing, No error, no crash, no rows deleted?

Tags: ios

Ok I recently followed a tutorial to implement an NSFetchedResultController
Its working great! I also found a question with an answer about how to delete a row. I added the suggested line of code to my implemetation file.

When you swipe left and press the delete button nothing happens. No errors, no row deleted and no crash.

Here's my code

```
    // Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];

        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            // handle error

        }
        else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
        }   
    }
}
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Is `tableView:commitEditingStyle:` called, or is `self.managedObject` nil?

Comment: I figured it out, I had [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]]; and it needed to be [context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]]; Thank you very much for your response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I had;

```
 [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
```

and it needed to be

```
[context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]]; Thank you very much for your response!
```